# How to reuse elements while using appium

Tags: mobile, appium, ui-automation, getelementbyid

I was wonder how can I reuse an elements while I'm using appium.

An elementSerarch returns an ID which is generated by Appium , I was wonder if there a way to reuse the same element by it's id ?

If not , then what is the purpose of the element's id ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create Page Object Model (POM) is the best way for element re-usability, but these reused elements do not essentially have the same Id on different pages so you might get.

> NoSuchElement Exception.

by separating out the reusable components will make your work more manageable.

Using POM You can store the elements into the variables, and pass them wherever you want.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz"));
```

---

Also Preferred selector order should be : id > name > css > xpath,
id and name are often the easiest and sure way.
xpath are often brittle, css are the way to go in conjunction of id and name !

But sometimes because of Page Refresh/Loading these elements might not be available on  later use so prefered way is to create Page Class and write methods to find these elements, like

```
 public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
           public void loginButton_Click() { 
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("xyz")).click();
}  
        }
```

Here you can list out all the methods to find the different elements on particular page, Now you just need to call the method whenever you want to use that element.

---

As far as Finding element by using it's Id is concern if you are using a tool such as uiautomatorviewer you will get the Developer generated Id's so you can use the same Id as many times as you want,

also if you are talking about the Id's generated by Appium such as: `info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"status":0}`

Here id : 1 is internal reference for appium to act, for future actions that we call for respective element in the test code. I preferred to use driver to find the elements,

---

**Id Of an Element**
Ideally the element.getId() method can be used to return a String, representing the ID of an element, But whenever I tried to use, It always returns 1 to me, You can also use,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("XOXOXOXO"));
element.getAttribute("id");
```

Finally You need this Id to perform Click/Swipe/long click and many other events you want for your Automation Testing, basically the process is like:

> Get the Id/name/xpath of an Element (By using different methods or
>   Tools like uiautomatorviewer)
>
> Find that element By Name/Id/xpath etc.
>
> Perform necessary operation

So Id is just one way to find the element, and you can reuse it by your own way.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer ! regarding the Appium's generated ID , what is the purpose of it , specially if there is a getter to it... where is it possible to use it ?

Comment: Do you want to use Id's that generated by Appium and shown in logs ??, I have tried element.getId() and it returns 1, as far as my knowledge Appium just find's Element by using the supporting strategy that we provide name/id/xpath etc, and if it founds that element it returns Selenium::WebDriver::Element object and if not found raises NoSuchElementError, so I'm confused where do I find the Id's you are talking about,

Comment: exactly , element.getId(). Why do I need this id ?

Comment: Please look at edited answer, I hope your doubt is clear, If I'm wrong or missing some point please let me know, Thanks & Regards

Comment: I think that I still missing something , I've found some element by name , appium has generated an unique (appium's id) for it , I do able to retrieve it by element.getId , but the question, what can I do with it and where I can use it ? I was thinking to try and reuse the element by the Id , but didn't find any method for it

Comment: I think that Id generated by Appium is for internal purpose, cause there must be some way for appium to keep track of different elements found, like if we find button element by id button101 and Appium might assign its own id with it like button123, so if you want to use button123 i.e. Id generated by Appium so its clear that first you need to find that element by its original Id i.e. button101, Than Appium will generate its own Id , So why to use Appium Id in the first place??and finding element by this Appium generated Id is really feasible, might be in some cases, let me know your openiun

Comment: Thanks for the answers